# sql replace by default

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

Is it possible to define a constraint on a column that will replace a certain input value by a default value?

I have a table with a type column that should always be a default value unless the user defines the type of the feature.

When the type is NULL, it will be replaced by the default value. Unfortunately the form handler does not fill in NULL when type is not defined. It fills an empty string instead.

How can I program SQL to replace these empty strings by the default value?

Code snip:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ACC_Plannen](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[PLANID] [nchar](50) NULL,
[plantype] [nvarchar](500) NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_ACC_Plannen_plantype]  DEFAULT ('Algemeen'),
```

Comment: Define it as `not null` instead of `null`

Comment: My guess is you need to do some work on the front end here because you say you  are getting empty strings. This means you are passing a value and the default constraint will be ignored because this isn't null.

Answer (score 0):

If you can only handle this on SQL, you can try few things:

- Create a stored procedure that will clean up input and insert/update your table;
- Create an insert/update trigger that will fix values for you.

Between the two above I'd go with stored procedure, because you have to explicitly call it while trigger does it's work implicitly. Might even add a trigger that raises error on invalid input instead of fixing it.

Ideally you would clean input before sending it to SQL though. Then you could just have `NOT NULL DEFAULT` constraint on your table.

Answer (score 0):

The main question is the following:  "Do you want to reject the insert and fix the data at the front end (user/application prgm).  Or just update the bad data on the back end (database)."

A [check constraint](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179491(v=sql.105).aspx) can be used to valid the data and make sure there is not empty string.  A violation results in a error.

A [after insert trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql) can be used to re-work (update) the empty string into what ever value you want.

Just be cognizant of the use case.

If you are bulk inserting and a check constraint fails, the whole batch is aborted.

If you are inserting a large amount of data, the trigger will be executed for each record.  Maybe a update statement after a large batch load in warranted in this case.

As always, it depends on your situation.

Happy coding!